# Error running C#/F# program on Mac OS

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, f#, .net-core

Both, the C# and F# hello world console application examples, fail with the following message:

**Debugger operation failed**
launch: program '' does not exist.

[image]

I can't get it to work properly. Microsoft site says that no additional stuff has to be installed for it to work properly [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-with-visual-studio-for-mac)

I already reinstalled visual studio which did not help. If I choose run -> run with custom configuration and turn off 'run in external console' it works fine. However I cannot find a setting to make this the default and I would love if it would just work and my installation was fine.

Hope someone has a clue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please transcribe your error message into the body of your question.

Comment: @TJWolschon done

Comment: I would just install Rider or VS Code.

Comment: Which IDE/editor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it, I added a symlink to the .NET binary in my $PATH. Apparently, the problem is that .NET isn't added to your path by default. Add the link through your terminal with the following:

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

I found this solution here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/420236/debugger-operation-failed-launch-program-does-not.html